# compare the rank of two poker cards

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I need to check the poker card ranks and see whether they're good hands. But I get compile error on the if conditions. I sorted the currentHand array first to make it easier.

```
int[] rankArray = currentHand.getRank(); 

 int[] sortedArray = Arrays.sort(rankArray);

   int r1 = sortedArray[0]; 
   int r2 = sortedArray[1]; 
   int r3 = sortedArray[2]; 
   int r4 = sortedArray[3]; 
   int r5 = sortedArray[4];
```

After that, I started from the "one pair" case.

```
 if (r1==r2) {
          if(r1>9 || r1=1) {
            winningHands = 1;
          }
   }//royal pair
```

But the compiler keeps on telling me that "illegal start of expression. What's the problem here?

Comment: Which line does it say is an "illegal start of expression"?

Comment: It's on r1==r2, and the error message is "identifier expected".

Comment: ... so it is not the error message you actually specified in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Like you've already done for `r1==r2`, use the `==` operator to compare; `=` is assign.

```
if (r1 > 9 || r1 == 1)
```

Also, [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-) sorts the array in place; it doesn't return anything.  Use

```
Arrays.sort(rankArray);
```

and use `rankArray` after that line.

Comment: Sorry, that was an typo. The problem is on the line r1==r2, and the error message is identifier expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` for comparing two things (as you already know); `=` is for assignment.